# DRMless AZW3 sent to Kindle Paperwhite from Calibre shows as having a very small number of pages

Tags: calibre, kindle-paperwhite

I bought *Excession* in AZW3, but the page numbers show up wrong on my Kindle Paperwhite when I load it from Calibre. The book shows as having only 4 pages.

The following did not help:

- Device > Configure this device > Check "Send page number information when sending books"
- Editing the file to remove NCX (there was none as far as I can tell)
- Editing the file to recreate the table of contents.

A screenshot of what I see on my Kindle:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this book in particular is that the person who created the AWZ3 file used `<div>` blocks for every paragraph instead of `<p>` blocks. Apparently the word-count plugin skips `<div>` text, so it only counts a few words in the Titles, etc.

I used Calibre to edit the book, as follows:

Tools > Transform HTML > Add rule

From there select "matches CSS Selector" and I filled in `div.fmtx1`. Then I selected "Change tag name" and set it to `p`. I made a second rule for `div.ftmx` as well. See screen shots:

[image]

[image]

Then I hit "OK". I also had to add a rule to the CSS to make the `<p>` tags render the same:

```
p {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.3;
}
```

Then I saved the book, loaded it on the Kindle again, and the page count is fixed:

[image]

The exact steps above won't work for every book (if they're using something other than a `div`, or a different class name other than `fmtx` and `fmtx1`), but knowing that you need `<p>` tags to get the text counted correctly should get you most of the way there.